# How to use the JdbcTemplate that is configured and available through Spring-Boot in the JobRepository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, jdbctemplate

Hiho,

we use Spring-Batch 4.3.5 inside a Spring-Boot 2.6.7 service. All things work fine so far. While unit testing the use-cases, we realized that the BatchAutoConfiguration/BatchConfigurerConfiguration creates a JobRepository. This JobRepository needs and wants some JdbcOperations. Because no instance of JdbcOperations is taken from the Spring application context while initializing all the beans, the JobRepositoryFactoryBean decides to create a fresh instance of type JdbcTemplate and attach it to the JobRepository.

Therefore I would like to ask if there is an 'easy' possibility to attach the instance of the JdbcTemplate that is provided by Spring-Boot? Is there another possibility as overwriting the whole initialization mechanism? Do we need to provide our own BatchConfigurer?

Any help is really appreciated! :)

Comment: You will need to configure your own, the code, which you can check, will always create a `JdbcTemplate` as only the `DataSource` will be injected. This is due to the assumption that your batch metadata is stored in a different database then the regular database (and thus it assumes cannot use the normal `JdbcTemplate`).

Comment: I second what @M.Deinum said. I added an answer with a code example. HTH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. You need to provide a custom `BatchConfigurer` and use any bean auto-configured by Boot to configure your job repository. Here is a quick example:

```
@Bean
public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(DataSource dataSource, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource) {
        @Override
        protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
            JobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
            factoryBean.setJdbcOperations(jdbcTemplate);
            // set other properties on the factory bean
            factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
            return factoryBean.getObject();
        }
    };
}
```

In this snippet, the `dataSource` and `jdbcTemplate` passed as parameters to the `batchConfigurer` method will be those auto-configured by Boot (and autowired by Spring).