# Spring Batch - How to create custom queries for the spring batch metadata tables

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

We have spring batch metadata tables configured in our project to store data related to job runs and we use **JobExplorer** to access data from them. Looking at the implementation behind the scenes, it has premade queries for those tables to extract the data.

Is there a simple way to create custom queries to get data from multiple tables at once?

These are the tables from which I need data:

**BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION** (job_execution_id, job_instance_id, status)

**BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS** (job_execution_id, key_name, string_val)

**BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE** (job_instance_id, job_name)

I want to be able to get the job status by passing in the job name and one of the job execution params

Comment: This has been answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72319173/how-to-use-the-jdbctemplate-that-is-configured-and-available-through-spring-boot